# solving T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log n

Tags: divide-and-conquer, recurrence

I am trying to solve T(n) = 2T(n/2) + log n

substituted n = 2^k

```
T(2^k) = 2T(2^(k-1)) + k  
T(2^k) = 2^2 T(2^(k-1)) + 2(k-1) + k

after k steps
T(2^k) = 2^k T(1) + 2^(k-1) + 2 * (2^(k-2)) +....+k
```

So basically I need to sum a term of i*2^i where i = 1 to log n - 1.
And I could not find an easy way to sum these terms. Am I doing something wrong ? Is there any other way to solve this recursion ? would master theorem work her ? if yes than how ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you should define a recursive export,say T(1)
then:
since T(2^k) = 2T(2^(k-1)) + k; *
we define g(k) = T(2^k)/2^k;
then * come into:
g(k) = g(k-1) + k/2^k = g(1) + sum(i/2^i); i=2,3,4...k
where g(1) = T(1)/2 = c;

where you could then unfold the sum expression and define it = y;
then unfold the expression of y/2;
y-y/2 is a geometric progression, so youcan solve it

as I worked out, sum = 3/2 - (k+2)/2^k;

so T(n) = 2^k * g(k) = (3/2+c)*n - (2+logn)

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram|Alpha gives a closed form solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%28n%29=2T%28n/2%29%2blog2%28n%29):

[image: recurrence]

[image: solution]

for a constant c_1 that is fixed by the initial condition.

By the way, log(n)/log(2) = lg(n), where lg is the base two logarithm.